# Error casting json data as [String: Any]

Tags: json, casting, swift3

I've created a datatask which downloads a json file.  The json is an array of dictionaries.  This is a sample of the data:

```
[
  {
    "userName": "Elon Musk",
    "comment": "This is a fantastic Beer.  I highly recommend it!"
  },
  {
    "userName": "SuperUser Account",
    "comment": "I agree with Elon.. It rocks!"
  }
]
```

The issue is I can't cast the json as `[String: Any]`. I can only cast it to `[Any]`. Here is the relevant code:

```
 guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        return
    }
    // now we have the json, let's just print it to prove we can access it
    print("The json is: " + json.description)
```

Cast as `[Any]` the json prints fine.  Anything else, the cast fails?

Thoughts please?

Edit.. This is the url:
http://www.smarttapp.com/DesktopModules/DnnSharp/DnnApiEndpoint/Api.ashx?method=GetCommentsFromArticleID&articleID=2240

Comment: You said yourself, it's an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary. Therefore you can't cast it to a dictionary. Did you mean to cast it to `[[String : Any]]` instead?

Comment: OMG!.... @Hamish. I can't believe I missed that!  I'll be able to sleep tonight! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is `array` not dictionary .. just cast it to `[[String:Any]]`

```
  guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] else {
       print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
       return
  }

  for dict in json {
      print(dict["userName"])
  }
```

Comment: Can someone please explain why I got three down votes as a result of not properly indenting a piece of code?